How can I remove black list from Indian embassy?
On the invitation of a theater group from the Indian state of Assam, two groups of 27 people entered India through the Sutarkandi border with visit visas.
The customs officer there stopped us from entering by showing us a violet visa issue. Later, at the request of higher authorities, we entered and completed the ceremony and returned.
A few days later one of the group of 27 traveled through another border and was intercepted, only to find out that the passports of all 27 of us had been blacklisted.
What is the way out of this problem?

Not that I can understand all these terms, but a border officer telling you someone else's passport is blacklisted? How can that happen?

Indian officer tr

When your passport are black listed then inform everywhere by ther site and list there. When you want to cross the border or airport then you will stoped. Same case with my team member and he protests and answar those
